# Can soapui maven plugin execute multiple projects parallel?

Tags: maven, soapui

My soapui project consists of multiple project files. Maven plugin configuration is as follows.Is there any way that I can make all the executions happen parallelly?

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>com.smartbear.soapui</groupId>
   <artifactId>soapui-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>5.2.1</version>
   <configuration>
       <junitReport>true</junitReport>
       .......
   </configuration>
   <executions>
      <execution>
         <id>exec1</id>
         <phase>test</phase>
         <goals>
             <goal>test</goal>
         </goals>
         <configuration>
             <projectFile>project1.xml</projectFile>
         </configuration>
      </execution>
      <execution>
         <id>exec2</id>
         <phase>test</phase>
         <goals>
             <goal>test</goal>
         </goals>
         <configuration>
             <projectFile>project2.xml</projectFile>
         </configuration>
      </execution>
   </executions>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

with redfish4ktc you can do this

Example :

```
<build>
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>com.github.redfish4ktc.soapui</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-soapui-extension-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>4.6.4.2</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>soapUI1</id>
                <phase>test</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>test-multi</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <projectFiles>
                        <scan>
                            <baseDirectory>./soapui/projects</baseDirectory>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/*_suffix.xml</include>
                            </includes>
                        </scan>
                    </projectFiles>
                    <outputFolder>./outputfolder</outputFolder>
                    <junitReport>false</junitReport>
                    <useOutputFolderPerProject>true</useOutputFolderPerProject>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

add to run this just execute the maven command :

```
mvn test com.github.redfish4ktc.soapui:maven-soapui-extension-plugin:4.6.4.2:test-multi
```